# WPF DataContext inheritance from MainWindow to UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, inheritance, code-behind, datacontext

I am a newbie in WPF, I have a problem concern DataContext inheritance from the MainWindow to a UserControl,
which will be attached as a Tabpage to the MainWindow's Tabcontrol.

My code snippets are as follows:

UserControlModel.cs

```cs
    public class UserControlModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (_name != value)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }

        // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }
```

ViewModelLocator.cs

```cs
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        private UserControlModel UserControlModel { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<UserControlModel> Users { get; set; }

        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            Users = new ObservableCollection<UserControlModel>
            {
                new UserControlModel { Name = "Albert" },
                new UserControlModel { Name = "Brian" }
            };
        }
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="VMLocator" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="330" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="592">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Margin="0,330,-1,-45" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="593">
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="490,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="330" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="592" >
        <TabItem x:Name="UserControlTabItem" Header="User Control">
            <Grid x:Name="UserControlTabpage" Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <local:UserControl VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{Binding Users, Source={StaticResource VMLocator}}" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

I create an instance of ViewModelLocator and bind Users instance to the UserControl in MainWindow.xaml.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```cs
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

UserControl.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="lbUsers" DisplayMemberPath="???" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="250" Margin="30,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="378"/>
</Grid>
```

UserControl.xaml.cs

```cs
        private ObservableCollection<UserControlModel> _users;

        public UserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            _users = ???;// How to reference the Users instance created in MainWindow ???

            lbUsers.ItemsSource = _users;
        }
```

Actually, I want to show the `Name` property of `UserControlModel` in the `ListBox`. If I am right, `UserControl` instance is
inherited with a `Users` instance as the `DataContext` from `MainWindow`. How can I reference the `Users` instance in the code-behind of `UserControl.xaml.cs`?

I have checked that `DataContext` in `UserControl` constructor is `null`! How come? What is the
correct way/place to test the `DataContext` in the code-behind?
Also, how to set `DisplayMemberPath` attribute of the `ListBox` in `UserControl.xaml`. Many thanks.

Comment: Did you solve your previous issue(s)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44670303/wpf-bind-different-usercontrols-to-different-viewmodels. Please remember to accept an answer then: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set or inherit DataContext in XAML of user control like this

UserControl.xaml

```
<dialogs:Usercontrol DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext}" />
```

Comment: After adding the suggested codes, I still cannot get the Users instance inside UserControl.xaml.cs. Thanks.

Comment: ViewModelLocator is the ViewModel of MainWindow right ? So you need to set it as DataContext of MainWindow like below

MainWindow.xaml.cs

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModelLocator();
    }

Comment: Sorry again, the DataContext of UserControl.xaml.cs is still null. Should I remove DataContext attribute from MainWindow.xaml: <local:UserControl2 VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{Binding Users, Source={StaticResource VMLocator}}" /> ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListBox` to the source collection. Since the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` is a `ObservableCollection<UserControlModel>`, you can bind to it directly:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ... />
```

Also make sure that you don't explicitly set the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` anywhere else in your code.

Although you should be able to reference the DataContext once the `UserControl` has been loaded:

```
public UserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        _users = DataContext as ObservableCollection<UserControlModel>;
    };
}
```

...there is no need to set the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListBox` in the code-behind. You should do this by creating a binding in the XAML.

Comment: The UserControl can bind to the Users instance from MainWindow instance now. But, DataContext of UserControl is still null. Thanks.